# nested mongodb queries in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, asynchronous

I have a MongoDB query, inside that, a foreach loop that calls another mongodb query a couple of times and pushes the results of the query in an array with each request. Now this is an asynchronous call, which means the next line that depends on this array

```
res.status(200).send(services);
```

will be executed and sends an empty array before being filled.

Code Snippet:

```
static async getServices(req, res) {
        let event_id = req.params.id;
        try {
            let services = [];
            await EventRepo.getEvent(event_id, (event) => {

                event.services.forEach(service_id => {
                    ServiceRepo.getService(service_id, (service) => {
                        services.push(service);
                    });
                });

                await res.status(200).send(services);   
            });
        } catch (exception) {
            res.status(500).send(exception)
        }
    }
```

I want it to be filled before sending the array, and I cannot nest the response sending inside this query:

```
event.services.forEach(service_id => {
    ServiceRepo.getService(service_id, (service) => {
        services.push(service);
        // Here for example
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the for each loop is the problem because it instantiates a promise in each iteration within another function, that is, the for each loop. Just use a normal for loop.